# Linux Mint 18 Xfce panel 4.12.0 Indicator plugin how to increase icon size

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, panel

Linux Mint 18 Xfce Panel indicator plugin – how to increase icon size.  The indicator plugin is the plugin that has the volume and the network connection status icons.

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331399/change-xfce-panel-launcher-icon-size) and it didn't work.

As per Ipor Sircer, the below image is an example of what an indicator plugin looks like on xfce.  The goal here is to increase the icon size of these and anything else that pops up in the indicator plugin:

[image]

Per ctac, here is what the indicator plugin properties looks like:

[image]

Here is a before and after of the resize to give you a better idea:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

The notification area has a place where you can change the icon size, so the notification area not changing icon size is normal.

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how.html)

Comment: I have no idea what you meant by that.  So I assume you meant more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer comes from [this](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=48454#p48454) post from ToZ.  Here is what he had to say:

> Square icons have recently been added to the indicator-plugin code base, but they won't really be available until the next release of Xfce (4.14). As an optional workaround, you could remove the indicator plugin from the panel and restart the panel. This will re-place the network manager icon in the notification area. For the sound icon, install "pnmixer" and add it to your autostart applications. This will add a volume icon to the notification tray.

Thank you ctac_ for directing me to the xfce forums.

Comment: Tanks to give here the answer you find somewhere else. I think you can accept your answer. This way it's marked at solved and if someone look at that, he can know it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

My Xfce is in French.

Modify where the mouse is located in the pictures.

1. Open Settings Manager

[image: Settings Manager]

2. Open Panel Preferences

[image: Panel Preferences]

3. Choose Items

[image: Choose Items]

4. Appearance

[image: Appearance]

Comment: I appreciate your reply, however your modifying the noticiation area, not the indicator plugin

Comment: Can't find your indicator plugin dialogbox in debian and on OpenBSD. When I resize the panel like in 2) the plugin icons grow . Perhaps it's your theme in Apparence which don't allow that. You can ask on https://forum.xfce.org/index.php

Comment: When trying to resize using your method, everything else resizes except for anything inside the indicator plugin.  I've started a thread at the URL you gave me.  https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12228